How can I connect my Windows Agent to my Datadog cluster agent in an EKS cluster?
Windows node agent can't connect to Datadog cluster agent on EKS cluster.
Loading Errors
  ==============
    orchestrator_pod
    ----------------
      Core Check Loader:
        Could not configure check orchestrator_pod: orchestrator check is configured but the cluster name is empty

      Python Check Loader:
        unable to import module 'orchestrator_pod': No module named 'orchestrator_pod'

Environment details

Agent version 7.56.0
Helm chart version 3.70.3
Kubernetes version 1.29
Provider AWS
Cluster type EKS cluster

I followed the Datadog documentation on how to used the cluster agent on a mixed cluster but even though the windows pods logs says it has connected to the cluster agent, the pod  doesn't get any information from the cluster like the cluster name or new tags.
Also, windows pods are the only ones that do not appear on datadog's website.
